# annotation mapping using hibernate select data from database and display on jsp page but error is below

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/konzern] threw exception [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: attendance is not mapped [from attendance a where a.status=:status]] with root cause

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: attendance is not mapped
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear: there is no entity named "attendance". Classes normally start with an upper-case letter, so maybe all you need is `from Attendance a`. If not, then show your code.

Comment: you need to provide your entity name and not the table name. Or may be you missed the annotation @Entity
@Table(name = "Attendance")

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple Problem, you just forgot to map your entity 'attendance'

use 
`@Entity
@Table(name="table_name",catalog="dbname")` on top of your entity(pojo class)
and add `<mapping class="package.attendance"/>` in hibernate configuration file.
Then problem will be solved.